# Echarts Line chart , display line name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts, apache-echarts

So I want to diplay my Linechart name at the end of each line and I'm not sure if this is possible with echarts

EXAMPLE :
On the image below there is a name at the end of each line

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using `series-line.endLabel`, as they do in the [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-race) you gave.

To specifically display the name of the series, you'll have to use a formatter on endLabel :

```js
endLabel: {
  show: true,
  formatter: function (params) {
    return params.seriesName;
  }
}
```

I also recommend you to increase `grid.right` so that the label won't be cropped.

Here is a simple example :

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '15%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210],
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.seriesName;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310],
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.seriesName;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Video Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410],
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.seriesName;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320],
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.seriesName;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.seriesName;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

myChart .setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked !!!! , I tried visiting https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html but something is wrong with the site css